# Localhost Facebook Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

Pulling my hair out here on this Facebook App. There are tons of posts already about this but none of the solutions seem to work.

I'm trying to test my Facebook app on my local system

```
FB.init({
      appId: "XXXXXXX"
});
```

Getting this

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

My URL:

http://localhost.myapp.com/mobile

Settings on Facebook:

```
App Domain: localhost

Website with Facebook Login: Checked
Site URL: http://localhost/mobile/

Mobile Web: Checked
Mobile Site URL: http://localhost/mobile/
```

Answer (score 0):

From your facebook app settings, add platform and provide this

> *Site Url: localhost:your_port*

No need to mention App domain to test from localhost. This worked for me in Website platform.